# emberjs - explain scheduleOnce in this context

Tags: ember.js

I have a nested component and I needed it to rerender on occassion.  First of all I tried to simply call the rerender method:

```
modelUpdated: function() {
  this.rerender();
}
```

But I got this error message:

> You can't use appendChild outside of the rendering process

The solution was to use the run loop but I'm confused as to why this works:

```
modelUpdated: function(model){
  Ember.run.scheduleOnce('render', this, 'rerender')
}
```

My understanding of `scheduleOnce` is that it will create a run loop if one does not exist and I the `rerender` method will be executed once in the render queue of the runloop.

I'm confused as to why this would go in the render queue and an explanation would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm confused as to why this would go in the render queue

It's normal that actions related to rendering go into render queue. Rendering logic happens in render queue. Rerendering is closely related to rendering, so to it's obvious that that it goes to render queue. Where would it go if not to render queue?

Taking queue descriptions from [The Run Loop guide](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/components/run-loop/#toc_what-happens-in-these-queues):

> The render queue contains jobs meant for rendering, these will
>   typically update the DOM

I think we can agree that `rerender` matches definition of `job meant for rendering` which will typically update DOM.

DOM update logic could also go to `afterRender` queue:

> The afterRender queue contains jobs meant to be run after all
>   previously scheduled render tasks are complete. This is often good for
>   3rd-party DOM manipulation libraries, that should only be run after an
>   entire tree of DOM has been updated

But `rerender` involves native Ember DOM rendering logic so it can't run after Ember rendering logic.

We can dive into Ember source code responsible for rendering/rerendering component - [rerender](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/tree/master/packages/ember-htmlbars/lib/node-managers/component-node-manager.js#L179), [render](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/tree/master/packages/ember-htmlbars/lib/node-managers/component-node-manager.js#L130). Both methods involve 
accessing `env.renderer` which is [`Renderer` class instance](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-metal-views/lib/renderer.js), by digging into it's source code we can see it's core of Ember specific rendering logic.